# Angularjs predicate on ng-if is not working

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement sorting for my AngularJS application using Predicate function. This is my code

```
<td>
    <a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'date'; reverse=!reverse">
        Time
        <span ng-show="predicate == 'date'">
            <span ng-show="!reverse">
                <img src="img/ascending.gif">
            </span>
            <span ng-show="reverse">
                <img src="img/descending.gif">
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
</td>

<td ng-if="SId==2">
    <a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'name'; reverse=!reverse">
        Name
        <span ng-show="predicate == 'name'">
            <span ng-show="!reverse">
                <img src="img/ascending.gif">
            </span>
            <span ng-show="reverse">
                <img src="img/descending.gif">
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
</td>

<td ng-if="SId==2">
    <a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'rno'; reverse=!reverse">
        RNO
        <span ng-show="predicate == 'rno'">
            <span ng-show="!reverse">
                <img src="img/ascending.gif">
            </span>
            <span ng-show="reverse">
                <img src="img/descending.gif">
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
</td>

<td ng-if="SId==1">
    <a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'phoneNumber'; reverse=!reverse">
        Phone Number
        <span ng-show="predicate == 'phoneNumber'">
            <span ng-show="!reverse">
                <img src="img/ascending.gif">
            </span>
            <span ng-show="reverse">
                <img src="img/descending.gif">
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
</td>
```

I have two dashboards, which are using the same HTML page. But Column names are different. So, column names are displayed based ng-if condition (SId = 1  is first dashboard & SId = 2  is second dashboard). Now columns are shown correctly in both dashboards. But when I implement sorting upon column names,  the column which is having ng-if condition is not sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-if` has its own scope. So when you do `predicate = 'rno'` inside an ng-if, you're *creating* a `predicate` attribute in the ng-if scope instead of modifying the controller scope's predicate.

Use a function to set the predicate:

```
$scope.sortBy = function(property) {
    $scope.predicate = property; 
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
}
```

and

```
<td ng-if="SId==2"><a href="" ng-click="sortBy('name')">
```

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet. It's working. But how to add icons here

Comment: No problem I got the answer.